# SPServices.SPAutocomplete cannot read property 'find' of undefined

Tags: spservices

I have created a SharePoint page and inserted text box using content editor web part with title of FilterTextBox

```
<input type="text" title="FilterTextBox"/>
```

and I have inserted below script using Script Editor web part

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $().SPServices.SPAutocomplete({ 
            sourceList: "Country",
            sourceColumn: "Title",
            columnName: "FilterTextBox",
            ignoreCase: true,
            numChars: 3,
            slideDownSpeed: 1000,
            debug: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

but I get the following error when page load

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined

what might be wrong with my code ?
thanks .

Answer (score 0):

This issue might occur if you don't add references for your `Jquery` , `SPService` , So make sure that you have the following references in your script.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/2014.02/jquery.SPServices-2014.02.min.js"></script>


<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $().SPServices.SPAutocomplete({    
            sourceList: "Country",
            sourceColumn: "Title",
            columnName: "FilterTextBox",
            ignoreCase: true,
            numChars: 3,
            slideDownSpeed: 1000,
            debug: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

Also, Make sure that The `sourceColumn` name is internalName for the column by going to List Settings > Edit Column > check the URL `Field=` parameter. but in your case, it's `Title` field that its internal name also `Title`

```
/_layouts/15/FldEdit.aspx?List=%7B53AE6414%2D62F1%2D4FF8%2D979A%2D86F80090776B%7D&Field=Title
```

**Note :**

- It's working with SharePoint 2010 ,  For more details check [$().SPServices.SPAutocomplete](https://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=$().SPServices.SPAutocomplete&referringTitle=Documentation)
- For SharePoint 2013 check [SPServices Stories #17: Multiple Form Fields Autocomplete for SharePoint 2010/2013 using JavaScript](http://sympmarc.com/tag/spautocomplete/)

Comment: they are already inclued in master page and i have used SpServices for Filter DropDown List in oither page .

Comment: @user6599525 what's the SharePoint version ?

Comment: 2013 Enterpise Edition

Comment: What's the version of Jquery file ? jQuery 1.11.x (SPServices 2013.01+) RECOMMENDED
jQuery 1.10.x (SPServices v0.7.2+)
NOT jQuery 1.9.x

Comment: Jquery version is 3.0.1 and and SpService is Version 2014.02

Comment: As my updated answer should you check this article it's said it's supported with SP 2010 https://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=$().SPServices.SPAutocomplete&referringTitle=Documentation I also add reference for SP 2013 in my answer , hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

So, after lots of searching around and viewing source, the KEY detail was to add the following before the "SharePoint:FormField" tag in my custom form:

```
<xsl:comment>FieldName="Account" FieldInternalName="Title"  FieldType="SPFieldText"</xsl:comment>
```

Thanks to **[this post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/176942/sputility-not-working-on-custom-edit-form?noredirect=1&lq=1)** for finally making that obvious, although I think I missed it in an earlier reference:  [SPServices Stories #17: Multiple Form Fields Autocomplete for SharePoint 2010/2013 using JavaScript](http://sympmarc.com/2013/10/07/spservices-stories-17-multiple-form-fields-autocomplete-for-sharepoint-20102013-using-javascript/)